# How to calculate number of weekes based on date in DataFrame Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, calculation

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["25.01.2020", and many more other dates...]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"], format = "%d%m%Y")
```

And I have a series of special dates like below:

```
special_date = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["16.01.2020",
                                         "27.01.2020",
                                         and many more other dates...], dayfirst=True))
```

And I need to calculate 2 more columns in this DataFrame:

col1 = number of weeks to the next special date

col2 = number of weeks after las special date

So I need results like below:

col1 = 1 because next special date after 25.01 is 27.01 so it is the same week

col2 = 2 because last special date before 25.01 is 16.01 so i is 2 weeks ago

*please be aware that I have many more dates, so code needs to work for more dates than only 2 special dates or only 1 data from df.

[image]

**I tried below code, but it calculate bad (give bad results):

```
delta = (s.to_numpy()[:,None] - df['data'].to_numpy()).astype('timedelta64[D]')  / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
n = np.min( delta, 0, where=delta> 0, initial=np.inf)
p = np.min(-delta, 0, where=delta<=0, initial=np.inf)

df['next'] = np.ceil(n/7) #consider np.floor
df['prev'] = np.ceil(p/7)
```

Comment: can you provide some of your data in question? something like `df.head(5)` and `special_date.head(5)` ?

Comment: From reading above question you have some df  and a series which contain some special dates. You need to find week difference between `df['date']` and `special_date` and put it in columns i.e Number of columns is equal to number of special dates? Am I right ?

Comment: number of weeks from te df["data"] to and after the nearest special date